# Usage of the word 技 (わざ) as well as similar words meaning "Technique"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, word-usage

I tend to hear this word a lot in anime, especially ones like Naruto. But there's little information on how it is used in conversation. According to Jisho, it means technique, art, skill and move with "technique" appearing to be the most prevalent meaning in most contexts.

So my question is how would it be used in conversation? (*Apologies if the question feels vague*, but one example should do it)

Also, is it formal or not and how does it differ from other similar words such as 手法, 技法, 技巧, 技術, and 術?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98322/45489